# Character encoding for use within ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, encoding, wpf-4.0

I'm creating a menu from a ListBox. I'm using FontAwesome to create some font-icons. This is part of the ListBox `ItemTemplate`.

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="FontAwesome" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               FontSize="32" Text="{Binding MenuCode}"
                               ToolTip="{Binding Tooltip}" >
```

The problem resides within the TextBlock's Text. I need to display the symbol, not the menu code. So, for example, if I use `Text="&#xf001;"` directly, then the music icon appears (fixed for all the items), but when I use DataBinding (each item has a different symbol): `Text="{Binding MenuCode}"` then the text `&#xf001;` (that is, the menu code as string) appears (as text, no icon). I guess problem is related with encoding, but can't fix it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong escape sequence. HTML uses '#&x' while C# uses \u. So your "#&xF001" would become "\uF001"